# systemTray-only application always has an open window

Tags: c#, wpf, system-tray

I'm developing C# a **WPF application** where all windows are hidden/closed by default. I have a **system tray** Icon (System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon) with a context menu to show/hide the windows. All windows have **ShowInTaskbar="False"**.

The problem is that the startup windows is still visible when I press **alt+tab**.
[image]
If I close the form that has the NotifyIcon my application stops, which I don't want.

I'm looking for a way to hide the windows completely without closing my application.

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have BOTH `ShowInTaskbar="False"` and `Visibility="Hidden"` set in the XAML and WPF should do this automatically.

The cause is likely you have window state set to minimized instead of visibility set to hidden.

Comment: It seems that adding Visibility="Hidden" to the forms XAML starts the window but then closes it, thus also closing my application.

Comment: It shouldent unless you have tied your entire code behind to the window load evend instead of the script init. Sounds like you have other issues. All hide does is literally hides the window but keeps it running.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "window load event" and "script init" please?

Comment: what do you have your window state set to?